# Can't find active excel using python win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to find the currently open excel file using win32com.
Below is my code:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks(2)
```

I tried different numbers instead of 2 ( excel.Workbooks(2)).
Does anybody have any idea why it not working?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about win32com.client but xlwings can be used to detect active excel.

```
import xlwings as xw
print(xw.books.active.name)
```